# Why would email provider require CNAME aliasing?

Tags: domain-name-system, email

I am looking at changing to a new web hosting provider for my domain and one I looked at was Zoho. However, on going through their process they are requiring a CNAME record to point to zmverify.zoho.com. I expected just an MX record change since this is just for email. I do not want to change my domain pointing, I just want to direct emails to Zoho.

Should I be concerned about this CNAME alias? Will it affect my web hosting? Why are they not just asking for an MX record change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to verify that you're the owner/technical administrator of the domain you want to use and the CNAME method is but one of the methods to [verify domain ownership](https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/domain-verification.html) they support.

In their words:

> Domain Verification is an essential step to ensure that the domain you added is Valid, Not expired and the user who added the domain has the required privileges to access DNS and decide about the email service for the domain. It is a mandatory step to ensure that the domain is not Spoofed domain and to prevent any loss of service due to the misuse of domain names.

Unless they ask you to set up a CNAME for a host entry you're already using (unlikely) it will not impact your website(s) and you can possibly even remove the CNAME afterwards.